# In every subfolder of source folder copy newest mp3 file to destination folder and delete old files

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script that does the following:

1. In the source directory find all subfolders
2. Within those subfolders find the newest mp3 file
3. Copy this mp3 file to the destination folder
4. If there is an old mp3 file in the destination folder, that is not the newest mp3 file in the subfolder of the source folder, delete it.

Here is a visualisation of the folder structure:

```
sourcefolder/
├─ subfolder 1/
│  ├─ Asound1.mp3
│  ├─ Asound2.mp3
│  ├─ Asound3.mp3
├─ subfolder 2/
│  ├─ Bsound1.mp3
│  ├─ Bsound2.mp3
```

Here is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the source directory containing subfolders
src_dir="PATH_SRC_DIR"

# Define the destination directory to copy the newest mp3 file
dest_dir="PATH_DEST_DIR"

# Create an empty array
files_to_keep=()

# Find the newest mp3 file in each subfolder of the source directory
find "$src_dir" -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "{}" && newfile=$(ls -t *.mp3 | head -n 1); echo "$PWD/$newfile"' \; | while read file; do
    echo "Newest file found: $file"
    # Add the newest file to the array
    files_to_keep+=("$(basename "$file")")
    # Copy the file to the destination directory
    cp "$file" "$dest_dir"
done

echo "Files to keep: ${files_to_keep[@]}"

# Delete the files in the destination directory that are not the newest files
for filename in "${files_to_keep[@]}"; do
    echo "Deleting files not named: $filename"
    find "$dest_dir" -type f ! -name "$filename" -delete
done
```

My script successfully copies the newest mp3 files into the destination folder, so it looks like this

```
destfolder/
├─ Asound3.mp3
├─ Bsound2.mp3
```

But if I add a file to the source folder so it looks like this:

```
sourcefolder/
├─ subfolder 1/
│  ├─ Asound1.mp3
│  ├─ Asound2.mp3
│  ├─ Asound3.mp3
├─ subfolder 2/
│  ├─ Bsound1.mp3
│  ├─ Bsound2.mp3
│  ├─ Bsound3.mp3  <-- new file
```

My script will have added the new file without deleting the old file (in this case it should delete Bsound2.mp3)

```
destfolder/
├─ Asound3.mp3
├─ Bsound2.mp3 <-- file should be deleted
├─ Bsound3.mp3
```

The problem is that it doesn't delete the old files, so I suspect there is an issue with the way I populate the array or something like that.

Comment: Turn off the `--delete` in your last `find` cmd and just see what files it "thinks" it should delete. Good luck.

Comment: note that if you have two filenames `f1` & `f2` and you do two commands `find ... ! -name f1 -delete`; `find ... ! -name f2 -delete` you will delete **every** file

Comment: The problem comes from piping into the while loop. A pipe create a subshell, so all the modifications to the `files_to_keep` variable are vanished once the while loop ends.

Comment: The echo in
`echo "Files to keep: ${files_to_keep[@]}"`
returns  "Files to keep: "
Which makes me think that I am not populating the array correctly here:
`# Add the newest file to the array
    files_to_keep+=("$(basename "$file")")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is it does not delete the old files.

Something like this might do what you wanted.

```
files_to_keep=()

while IFS= read -r directory; do
  (
  cd "$directory" || exit
  new_file=$(ls -t *.mp3 | head -n1)
  echo "$PWD/$newfile"
  printf 'Newest file found: %s\n' "$new_file"
  file_name=$(basename "$new_file")
  files_to_keep+=("$file_name")
  cp "$new_file" "$dest_dir" || exit
  )
done < <(find "$src_dir" -type d)
```

---

- The `ls` can be replace with something better maybe with GNU `find` feature.
- There might be a few bugs from the scripts above, I haven't really tested it thoroughly though.

---

Since I'm not particularly a fan of [ParsingLS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), this might be an alternative:

```
files_to_keep=()

while IFS= read -rd '' directory; do
  latest=
  shopt -s nullglob
  for f in "$directory"/*.mp3; do
    [[ "$f" -nt "$latest" ]] && latest="$f"
  done
  shopt -u nullglob
  [[ -n "$latest" ]] && {
    printf 'Newest file found: %s\n' "$latest"
    file_name=$(basename "$latest")
    files_to_keep+=("$file_name")
    cp -v "$latest" "$dest_dir" || exit
  } 
done < <(find "$src_dir" -type d -print0)
```

---

- GNU `cp`(1) has the `-u` flag/option, for whats its worth.

---

```
for i in "${!files_to_keep[@]}"; do
  files+=(-o -name "${files_to_keep[$i]}")
done

find "$dest_dir" -type f ! \( "${files[@]:1}" \) -exec echo {} +
```

---

- Replace the `-exec echo {} +` with `-delete` or `-exec rm -rf {} +` If you're satisfied with the output.

---

A small snippet about the array `files` above.

```
files_to_keep=({1..5}.mp3)

for i in "${!files_to_keep[@]}"; do
  files+=(-o -name "${files_to_keep[i]}")
done

##: Note: Just for the human eyes to see DO NOT
##: use or parse in scripts.

printf -- '-type f ! \( %s \)\n' "${files[*]:1}"
```

Output (which `find` receives and process).

```
-type f ! \( -name 1.mp3 -o -name 2.mp3 -o -name 3.mp3 -o -name 4.mp3 -o -name 5.mp3 \)
```

---

See the following links:

- [UsingFind](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind)
- [GNU Find](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html)
- [POSIX Find](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)
- [Find-execs-rm-vs-delete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167823/finds-exec-rm-vs-delete)
- [Understanding-the-exec-option-of-find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find)
- [How can I get the newest (or oldest) file from a directory?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/099)
- [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! I am getting this error: "cp:PATH_SRC_DIR/1 is a directory (not copied)."
To me it looks like "/1" is added to the source path somewhere which causes the error, do you know why?

Comment: @hjesper, If you could put an `echo` before the `cp` or debug by using `set -x` after the `shebang` that could point you to the source of the error, sorry I haven't had the time to test the scripts thoroughly.

Comment: @hjesper, I think I might have found the source of the error, added `file_name=$(basename "$new_file")` and `file_name=$(basename "$latest")`

Comment: @hjesper, been busy here and there but I moved the `latest=` variable assignment inside the `while` loop before the nested `for` loop to always start a with an empty `latest` variable. That should fix everything now.

Comment: Amazing, that worked! Thank you so much!
What can I do to only copy in the files if they don't already exist in the destination folder?

Comment: As mentioned in my post if you have GNU `cp(1)` then use the `-u` flag, otherwise test the file at the destination directory, something like `[[ ! -e "$dest_dir/my_cool_music.mp3 ]] && cp ...` or something like that... but its starting to sounds like you/we are just reinventing `rsync` from scratch... ;-)

Comment: Wow i didn't know rsync existed! Maybe this whole thing should have been written using that instead? If it's not too much trouble I would to hear how you would do it, otherwise thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @hjesper, we have exhausted our comment section but there are quite a handful of entries for rsync in this forum or at unixstackexchange.com